# Function of probability measures representation

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mu$ be a in $\mathbb M(\mathbb R)$, the space of probability measure on $\mathbb R$.

Let $F$ be in $C_b (\mathbb M(\mathbb R), \mathbb R)$, the space of continuous bounded function on $\mathbb M(\mathbb R)$ into $\mathbb R$.

**Question:**

Is there a function $f \in C_b(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ such that $F$ can be represented as
$F(\mu) = \int f(x) \mu(dx)$?

Comment: If there exists such $f$, then $F$ is linear, right?

Comment: Even if we assume that $F$ is linear (as well-spotted by @LuizCordeiro), what is the topology that you endow $\Bbb M(\Bbb R)$ with?

Comment: If $F$ is linear it is hardly bounded in the sense that $|F(P)|\le C$ for some $C$ (except if $F=0$). Thus Luiz' remark answers the question.